# UILocalNotification gets lost on app switcher

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, taskmanager

I'm writing a countdown app for iOS in Swift that also works in the background by setting local notifications to fire in the amount of seconds missing to completion when the user leaves the app.
Everything seems to be working as intended both on iOS 7.1 and beyond, but there's a glitch I can't seem to solve (or find info about): if I leave the app by double clicking the home button and I stay in the app switcher, the notifications get lost: they are set but they are not displayed. This happens only if I stay on the app switcher directly from the app itself. If I leave the app through the home screen and then call the app switcher, the notifications are displayed properly. 
It looks like local notifications get lost if I don't leave the 'limbo' of the first app switcher execution with the app in the foreground.
Has anybody encountered the same behavior?
I admit that this is kind of an edge case, but it's still something I would like to take care of.

Here is the code I'm using to set the local notifications, under `applicationWillResignActive`(this one is for the notification for when the countdown reaches halftime):

```
        let notificationHt: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        notificationHt.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        var notDelayHt = Double((missingTargetCentSecs/100)-((totalTargetMinutes*60)/2))
        notificationHt.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: notDelayHt)
        notificationHt.alertBody = "Half time!"
        notificationHt.alertAction = nil
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notificationHt)
```

Comment: Please show the code where you are creating the local notifications - specifically, which app delegate method are you doing this in?

Comment: I've added the code for the notifications. I'm pretty sure that they are scheduled correctly because they work fine if I leave the app switcher. There's also some output log text in the same block of code that tells me they've been scheduled and for when.

Comment: for what it's worth - I can confirm this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! So it might be a bug, I will try to dig in the developer forums, although there doesn't seem to be anything related.